# Undo or redo option creating opencv image processing (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, undo-redo

I am new in image processing. I tried a very basic program to measure the distance between two points of an image using click events to analyse some diameters. But sometimes I am getting wrong points due to miss click. I want to code a undo option so that I can correct miss clicks. I will appreciate your suggestion. My code is below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('nanoTube.tif')

def click_event(event, x, y, flags, param):
if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    cv2.circle(img, (x,y), 2, (0, 0, 200), -1)
    points.append((x, y))

    if len(points) == 2:
        cv2.line(img, points[-1], points[-2], (255,0,220), 5)
        distance(points)
        points.clear()

    cv2.imshow('image', img)

def distance(points):
    a = points[0]
    b = points[1]

    x1 = a[0]
    y1 = a[1]

    x2 = b[0]
    y2 = b[1]

    diameter = np.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)

    dis.append(diameter)
    print(dis)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', click_event)
points = []
dis = []

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: there are countless ways to achieve that. are you sure you cannot come up with your own solution? first thing is to not remove the points when you have clicked a second time. beyond that there are so many possible solutions. keep the points until you hit another key or button. maybe update a point when you click close to it (closer than the distance you're going to measure), click left for point 1, right for point 2 and update distance every time... you get the idea

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I am struggling with it last few days. Can you help more in detail? Any document or similar type coding hint would be okay.